# reticulate segfaults with call to plt.plot()

Tags: r, reticulate

I am encountering a segfault when I make a reticulated call to
`matplotlib.pyplot.plot()`.

---

Steps to produce error:

1. Create a `Dockerfile` with the contents:

   ```
   FROM rocker/r-ver:latest

   RUN apt update && apt install -y python3.8-venv python3.8-dev

   RUN install2.r --error reticulate

   COPY test.R /root/
   ```
2. Create a file `test.R` (in the same location) with the contents:

   ```
   reticulate::virtualenv_create(
     envname = "./venv",
     packages = c("matplotlib")
   )

   reticulate::use_virtualenv("./venv")

   reticulate::py_run_string("import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.plot([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])")
   ```
3. Build an image from the `Dockerfile`: `docker build . --tag="segfault-reprex"`
4. Try to run `test.R` in the running container: `docker run segfault-reprex Rscript /root/test.R`. This gives the full traceback listed below.

---

Full traceback

```
Using Python: /usr/bin/python3.8
Creating virtual environment './venv' ... Done!
Installing packages: 'pip', 'wheel', 'setuptools', 'matplotlib'
Collecting pip
  Downloading pip-21.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.7 MB)
Collecting wheel
  Downloading wheel-0.37.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
Collecting setuptools
  Downloading setuptools-60.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (958 kB)
Collecting matplotlib
  Downloading matplotlib-3.5.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.whl (11.3 MB)
Collecting kiwisolver>=1.0.1
  Downloading kiwisolver-1.3.2-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.whl (1.2 MB)
Collecting fonttools>=4.22.0
  Downloading fonttools-4.28.5-py3-none-any.whl (890 kB)
Collecting packaging>=20.0
  Downloading packaging-21.3-py3-none-any.whl (40 kB)
Collecting cycler>=0.10
  Downloading cycler-0.11.0-py3-none-any.whl (6.4 kB)
Collecting numpy>=1.17
  Downloading numpy-1.22.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (16.8 MB)
Collecting pillow>=6.2.0
  Downloading Pillow-9.0.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (4.3 MB)
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.7
  Downloading python_dateutil-2.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (247 kB)
Collecting pyparsing>=2.2.1
  Downloading pyparsing-3.0.6-py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
Collecting six>=1.5
  Downloading six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Installing collected packages: pip, wheel, setuptools, kiwisolver, fonttools, pyparsing, packaging, cycler, numpy, pillow, six, python-dateutil, matplotlib
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 20.0.2
    Uninstalling pip-20.0.2:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-20.0.2
  Attempting uninstall: setuptools
    Found existing installation: setuptools 44.0.0
    Uninstalling setuptools-44.0.0:
      Successfully uninstalled setuptools-44.0.0
Successfully installed cycler-0.11.0 fonttools-4.28.5 kiwisolver-1.3.2 matplotlib-3.5.1 numpy-1.22.0 packaging-21.3 pillow-9.0.0 pip-21.3.1 pyparsing-3.0.6 python-dateutil-2.8.2 setuptools-60.5.0 six-1.16.0 wheel-0.37.1
Virtual environment './venv' successfully created.

 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x7ffaeabe1100, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: py_run_string_impl(code, local, convert)
 2: reticulate::py_run_string("import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.plot([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])")
An irrecoverable exception occurred. R is aborting now ...
```

---

Things I have noted:

1. A minimal example inovling eg. the pandas package, rather than matplotlib,
   runs successfully. ie. if `test.R` contains:

   ```
   reticulate::virtualenv_create(
     envname = "./venv",
     packages = c("pandas")
   )

   reticulate::use_virtualenv("./venv")

   reticulate::py_run_string("import pandas as pd; df = pd.DataFrame()")
   ```
2. If you enter the container interactively (`docker run -it segfault-reprex /bin/bash`),
   run `test.R` (`Rscript /root/test.R`), activate the resulting
   virutalenv (`source /root/venv/bin/activate`), you can use matplotlib fine from
   python (`python -c "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.plot([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])"`)
3. The reticulate documentation states that:

   > for reticulate to bind to a version of Python it must be compiled with shared
   > library support (i.e. with the --enable-shared flag)

   `docker run -it segfault-reprex /usr/bin/python3 -c "import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_config_vars('Py_ENABLE_SHARED'))"`
   shows that the container's Python was compiled with shared library support

Comment: Have you tried to create an image starting from python and then installing R? This has worked for me one time when I needed to use both python and R in the container. It wasn't working the other way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the R binary in `rocker/r-ver:latest` is compiled against a different BLAS library to the one which the numpy on PyPI is compiled against.

This was explained to me by Tomasz Kalinowski [here](https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/issues/1133#issuecomment-1021783041).

The solution is to ensure numpy uses the same BLAS libraries as `rocker/r-ver`'s R binary does. An easy way to ensure this is to compile numpy from source. This compilation could be performed at either image *build-time* or container *runtime*.

#### Compiling numpy at runtime

To compile numpy at container runtime we can leave our `Dockerfile` as is, and add a call to `system2()` *after* our initial call to `reticulate::virtualenv_create()`. Altering `test.R` to become:

```
reticulate::virtualenv_create(
  envname = "./venv",
  packages = c("matplotlib")
)

system2("./venv/bin/pip3", c("install",
                             "--no-binary='numpy'",
                             "numpy",
                             "--ignore-installed"))

reticulate::use_virtualenv("./venv")

reticulate::py_run_string("import matplotlib.pyplot as plt;plt.plot([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])")
```

After rebuilding our image, we can run `test.R` in this container without segfault!

#### Compiling numpy at build-time

Compiling numpy at runtime adds ~3 mins to *every* call of our R script!

A better solution could be to perform this compilation at image *build-time*. This would mean we'd only have to wait those ~3 minutes once (at image build time), rather than *every time* we run our script!

A `Dockerfile` to do so could look like:

```
FROM rocker/r-ver:latest

RUN apt update && apt install -y python3 python3-dev python3-venv

RUN install2.r --error reticulate

# Create a venv
RUN python3 -m venv /root/venv

# Compile numpy from source into venv
RUN /root/venv/bin/pip3 install --no-binary="numpy" numpy --ignore-installed

COPY test.R /root/
```

The accompanying test.R file would then make use of `reticulate::virtualenv_install()` as:

```
reticulate::virtualenv_install(
  envname = "/root/venv",
  packages = c("matplotlib")
)

reticulate::use_virtualenv("/root/venv")

reticulate::py_run_string("import matplotlib.pyplot as plt;plt.plot([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])")
```

NB. when running a container from the image with numpy already compiled, you'll need to run as either root (`-u="root"`), or else change the permissions on the compiled numpy version in the `Dockerfile`; otherwise you will encounter a permissions error.